# PHP/Myadmin Query gives empty variable back but db is full

Tags: php, variables

It is pretty weird. My query works because it returns all the values from the data base except for one. I can't get the token of the data base. The only difference is that the token column is in a longtext format. Maybe it has to do with the format?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

require 'dbh.inc.php';


$selector = "e03a9e2f7e09ea81";
$currentDate = 1588926114;
$validator = "69d8afa6ecfb1ffd1c1e1605beee4f25161820544231ff2b83c38511fce412f1";

echo "vor SQL </br>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pwdreset WHERE pwdResetSelector=? AND pwdResetExpires >= ?"; 
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $selector, $currentDate);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$mysqliErfolgreich =  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $email, $resetSelector, $resetToken, $expires);
echo "bind_resultErfolgreich" . $mysqliErfolgreich ."</br>";
if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
echo "Variable 1: ".$id ."</br>";
echo "Variable 2: ".$resetSelector ."</br>";
echo "Variable 3: ".$resetToken ."</br>";
echo "Variable 4: ".$expires ."</br>";
echo "Variable 5: ".$email ."</br>";
}
```

Output on website:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwUAp.png - you can see every variable is returned except for the token -.-

my data base: there is an entry in the token column:

The definitions of the column by phpmyadmin (token is longtext, rest is text and int)

Comment: The variable order in the mysqli_stmt_bind_result() function argument list differs from the output order. Is that intentional?

Comment: Have you tried calling `mysqli_store_result()`? There's a comment in the docs for `bind_result()` that suggests you _must_ do that if your results include a longtext field.

Comment: @droopsnoot thanks for the answer. Yeah I just had to add it before the bind_result(). A friend of mine sent me this link as well (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47928). It works now (: